# Tesla AC motor: question on component

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, induction-motor

The following is a picture of Tesla’s AC motor patent. **Does anyone know what appears to be slip rings on the left end of shaft a’ coming from generator G are for?  Also, what is the function of the inverted Y shape with two terminals on its end?**

The operation of the motor with the cos and sin waveforms above and below each magnet makes sense, but I’m confused by the connections on the end of the shaft.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing an inverted Y shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wires from the rotor windings enter the rectangular aperture on the hollow shaft and emerge at the end to feed the slip rings.

The slip rings are used to get the AC electricity out

Presumably this is done to avoid a bearing which is not shown in this illustration

Comment: Thanks I see that the end of the shaft has four wires protruding and not two.

Comment: I guess the other two enter on the back of the shaft.

Comment: I see four wires coming from the coils and four out the end of the shaft. I did not see that before